# stdin to stdout after processing

Tags: c, stdout, stdin

I have a utility that is supposed to optimize files by transforming them into an alternate file-format. If it cannot make the files smaller, I would like the original file returned.

The design is to use `stdin` in and `stdout` for input and output. This is for a case where the processed size is larger than the original file size. All other branches are tested as working.

```
  char readbuffer[65536];
  ssize_t readinbytes;
  while ((readinbytes = fread(readbuffer, sizeof(char), insize, stdin)) > 0) {
    if (fwrite(readbuffer, sizeof(char), readnbytes, stdout) != readnbytes) {
      fatal("can't write to stdout, please smash and burn the computer\n");
    }
  }
```

**Problem** This is resulting in a file with size 0

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Given the code it looks like "cruft" is standing for "nothing".

Comment: How can you tell what is cruft in a binary file?

Comment: I'm trying to send stdin as-is at start of the program to stdout after working with stdin. 

I know stdin not being closed, but I remember something about it being a PITA if accessed before. I tried fseek to reset position in stream so that I could read from first byte of stdin to last. Up to 64k at a time.

Comment: @WeatherVane this attempts to fit values into smaller values, checks if file-size is different after changes. If a file has too many unique chunks, there is no saving, so just output file as-is. I don't need the program written, it's this case I just can't seem to crack it

Comment: OT: `sizeof(char)` equals 1 by definition and you are already using that fact implicitly, when you pass `sizeof(readbuffer)` as the number of elements.

Comment: @Bob__ I've actually tried switching those operands around too. Same result. zero-length file

Comment: What's the resulting file?  It writes to stdout, are you using a shell to redirect the output?  What command-line are you using?  If you are redirecting to an existing file then the shell will truncate it to zero bytes before running your program.

Comment: @cdarke usage: `./executable < /path/to/in -flags > /path/to/out`
I think the problem is that I'm using stdin to send to utilities, I'm pretty sure that is emptying the stream... I don't use C often because of weird quirks like this. If I use a different mode (any other flags) my program works just fine, it's this return stdin if optimized is > original case.

Comment: What do you mean by sending to utilities?  Are those called by the C executable?  Its not a particularly weird quirk - most command-line utility programs are written in C and it works the same in all the languages I have ever seen.

Comment: utilities (other C code via libraries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right this question has a strange answer. Essentially I had to read `stdin` into a buffer (`inbuf`), then output the contents of that buffer. The overarching reason I was getting no output was multi-faceted.

1. Firstly I'd failed to spot a branch which already determined if the input buffer was smaller than the output buffer

   ```
   if((readinbytes < outbuffersize) || force) {
       // inside this is where the code was...
   ```
2. It looks like (because stdout was being used to write to) there was a section that contained a log statement that was not output in the matching `else` block. The code inherited was terribly formatted so it was never picked up on.

   As outputting error messages is not fulfilling the purpose of the utility (always output a valid output file if a valid input file is provided)

**solution** (`stdin` is read into `inbuf` at the start of the program)

```
set_filemode_binary(stdout);
if (fwrite(inbuf, 1, readinbytes, stdout) != insize) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error writing to stdout\n");
    free(inbuf);
    exit(3);
}
```

**errata** (reading in `stdin`)

```
unsigned char * inbuf = NULL;
size_t readinbytes;
long insize = 0;

// elsewhere...

// die if no stdin
insize = getFileSize(stdin);
if (insize < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "no input to stdin\n");
    exit(2);
}
// read stdin to buffer
inbuf = createBuffer(insize); // wrapper around malloc handling OOM
if ((readinbytes = fread(inbuf, sizeof(char), insize, stdin)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error reading from stdin\n");
    free(inbuf);
    exit(3);
}
```

*Also* don't forget to `free(inbuf)`.

```
if(inbuf){ free(inbuf); }
```

I Hope this helps someone.

Comment: It should also be noted there are easier more widely compatible ways to handle the buffer. Also you either need to deal with buffer overflow, or realloc the memory space (which eats RAM) for n-length files.

The end solution I proposed (still hasn't been merged upstream) allow a max-size read-bytes option through CLI args.